# COBOL illegal file name

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cobol, printers

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. HENSEM as "Test1.Program1".

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

   SELECT CUSTOMER-FILE
           ASSIGN TO "CUSTOMER.DAT"
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.

   SELECT PRINTER-FILE
           ASSIGN TO PRINTER
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.


   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   FD CUSTOMER-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
      01 CUSTOMER-RECORD.
      05 CUSTOMER-NAME PIC X(30).
      05 CUSTOMER-PRODUCT PIC X(20).
      05 CUSTOMER-QUANTITY PIC 9(2).
      05 CUSTOMER-DATE PIC X(10).

   FD PRINTER-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED.
       01 PRINTER-RECORD PIC X(80).


   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

  *VARIABLES FOR SCREEN ENTRY
   01 Y-N PIC X.
   01 ENTRY-STATUS PIC X.


   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   OPEN EXTEND CUSTOMER-FILE.
   OPEN OUTPUT PRINTER-FILE.
   MOVE "Y" TO Y-N.
   PERFORM ADD-RECORDS
       UNTIL Y-N = "N".
   PERFORM CLOSING-PROCEDURE.



       GOBACK.

  * OPENING AND CLOSING

   OPENING-PROCEDURE.


   CLOSING-PROCEDURE.
       CLOSE CUSTOMER-FILE.
       MOVE SPACE TO PRINTER-RECORD.
       WRITE PRINTER-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING PAGE.
       CLOSE PRINTER-FILE.

   ADD-RECORDS.
       MOVE "N" TO ENTRY-STATUS.
       PERFORM GET-FIELDS
           UNTIL ENTRY-STATUS = "Y".
       PERFORM ADD-THIS-RECORD.
       PERFORM ANY-MORE.

   GET-FIELDS.
       MOVE SPACE TO CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       DISPLAY "ENTER CUSTOMER NAME: ".
       ACCEPT CUSTOMER-NAME.
       DISPLAY "ENTER WHAT DID THE CUSTOMER BOUGHT: ".
       ACCEPT CUSTOMER-PRODUCT.
       DISPLAY "ENTER HOW MUCH DID THE CUSTOMER BOUGHT: ".
       ACCEPT CUSTOMER-QUANTITY.
       DISPLAY "ENTER WHEN DID THE CUSTOMER BOUGHT: ".
       ACCEPT CUSTOMER-DATE.
       PERFORM VALIDATE-FIELDS.

   VALIDATE-FIELDS.
       MOVE "Y" TO ENTRY-STATUS.
       IF CUSTOMER-NAME = SPACE
           DISPLAY "CUSTOMER NAME MUST BE ENTERED"
       MOVE "N" TO ENTRY-STATUS.

   ADD-THIS-RECORD.
       MOVE CUSTOMER-RECORD TO PRINTER-RECORD.
       WRITE CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       WRITE PRINTER-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING 1.

   ANY-MORE.
       DISPLAY "IS THERE ANY MORE INPUT?".
       ACCEPT Y-N.
       IF Y-N = "Y"
           MOVE "Y" TO Y-N.
       IF Y-N NOT = "Y"
           MOVE "N" TO Y-N.


   END PROGRAM HENSEM.
```

My problem is the OPEN OUTPUT FILE-PRINTER LINE. The program does not run and I'm getting illegal file-name error. If I delete that whole line, it runs but later produces error at WRITE PRINTER-RECORD BEFORE ADVANCING 1. Thank you.

Comment: You need to post the full text of all the messages.

Comment: It's been decades since I dealt with COBOL, but I don't see the printer name specified anywhere, and that does seem to be the root of your problem.

Comment: @CareyGregory Do I have to specify the name during the SELECT PRINTER-FILE?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [assign a device name to your file](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx20books/fhname.htm#s009) using one of the standard Windows symbolic names, instead of the COBOL keyword PRINTER:

```
SELECT PRINTER-FILE
    ASSIGN TO "lpt1"
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

Comment: For some more hints on printing with COBOL, see the GNU Cobol FAQ, 3.15 How do I print to printers with GNU Cobol, with a pretty easy way to get PDF output with a single CALL and cups-pdf.